# phpword removeblock - table still exist

Tags: php, phpword

I have a docx template containing both text and a table, before and after which I added

`{blockname} {/blockname}`

Calling

`$templateProcessor->replaceBlock('blockname', '');`

deletes the text, but not the table. Any suggestions why?

Comment: Did you tried deleteBlock('blockname') instead of replace?

Comment: Yes. The same effect

Comment: I guess you use PHPOffice/PHPWord. Maybe it is a bug if it delete/remove the text but not the table, so I suggest to make a bug report.